# Request https con certificado no válido y HttpClient

Tags: genexus

Estoy intentando conectarme con HttpClient a una url https con un certificado autogenerado.

¿Hay alguna forma para que no se valide si es un certificado válido?

Answer (score 0):

Si instalas el certificado en el equipo en el que estás haciendo la solicitud entonces ese certificado va a ser válido dentro del equipo únicamente, permitiendo hacer la solicitud sin problemas.